# How many unique four-letter permutations can be constructed using the letters in the word ALGEBRA without repetition?

Tags: combinatorics

> How many unique four-letter permutations can be constructed using the letters in 'ALGEBRA' without repetition?

I would have guessed that a solution would be as follows.

Total number of permutations: $\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}=\frac{7!}{3!}=840$

Number of permutations containing both 'A's (so two 'A's plus two other letters):
$\frac{5!}{2!(5-2)!}=\frac{5!}{2!3!}=10$.

Each of these can be combined in $4!=24$
So there is a total of $10 \cdot 24=240$ containing two 'A's.
So half this number should be subtracted from the total: $840-120=720$.

But this is wrong. Where am going wrong?

Comment: Do you mean combinations or permutations?  That is, do you wish to just select four of the six distinct letters (combinations) or arrange the four letters you select (permutations)?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I mean permutations, sorry. But it is allowed for a permutation to contain two 'A's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments , it appears that question is asking for how many possible words of length four there are using only the elements from the set of $\{A,A,L,G,E,B,R\}$.

When we construct the words ,we have two selection such that

- All possible words with distinct letters (repeated letters not used) : If the letters of our words are distinct , select four letters from $\{A,L,G,E,B,R\}$ ,and order them in a row such that $$\binom{6}{4}4!=360$$
- All possible words with repetition used: If repetiton is used , the repeating letters is only $A's$ , so select two more letters to construct your words,and order them in a row.Do not forget division rule because of repeating letters.Then ,
  $$\binom{5}{2}\frac{4!}{2!}=120$$

As a result ,we have  $360+120=480$ distinct words with your restriction at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good problem to gently introduce generating functions.

All the $5$ letters except $A$ can occur $0\;or\;1$ time, and can be represented by $(x^0 + x^1)$ **each**, the coefficients of $x$ indicating use $0,1$ times, so for non-repeating letters,  we can write as $(x^0 +x^1)^5$

The letter $A$ may occur $0,1,\;or\; 2$ times, and when used twice we must divide by $2!$ as is the rule in permutations, thus represent this as $(x^0+x^1 +\frac{x^2}{2!})$

The last step is to [find](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=coefficient+of+x%5E4+in+4%21%28x%5E0+%2B+x%5E1%29%5E5%28x%5E0%2Bx%5E1%2Bx%5E2%2F2%21%29), for a word size of $4$,

coefficient of $x^4$ in $4!(x^0+x^1)^5(x^0+x^1 +\frac{x^2}{2!}) = 480$

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to this so don't be afraid to explain what I got wrong.

You have seven letters and four spots. However, you also have two copies of distinguishable A's. The total number of orderings is $\frac{7!}{3!2!}$ = 420

We want at most one A to be chosen. We can subtract the total from the number of combinations with two A's.

There are two spots we want to put the two indistinguishable A's in. $\binom{4}{2}$. We have two spots left and five distinguishable letters. $\frac{5!}{3!}.$ After multiplying we get 120.

420 - 120 = 300 orderings.

Comment: I would suggest waiting for clarification on the question.  See my comment at the bottom of the question.  If you are trying to count the number of arrangements of four distinct letters drawn from the word ALGEBRA, your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Oh ok my bad :(